# How can I get the fastboot command?

Tags: fastboot

I'm trying to root my KF 6.3 following this article. 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1568340&page=1

Now I'm in Kindle Fire screen (fastboot mode) but fastboot is missing.

```
hieund@hieund:~/Downloads/KF/RestoreRootFor6.3$ fastboot -i 0x1949 flash bootloader u-boot.bin
fastboot: command not found
```

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and have adb installed.

Comment: Getting quick answers to problems is not one of this site's strengths. It works best for questions that have an answer and which will help future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Fastboot** is a binary and protocol used to communicate with Android devices in the early boot stage. It allows to change of the boot target and therefore is often used to install custom boot-loader (TWRP, clockworkmod, etc.) and ROMs.

The binary often comes with the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), for example on my linux system it is installed at `/opt/android-sdk-update-manager/platform-tools/fastboot`. There are also [build instructions for fastboot](http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html) on the official android page.

Comment: My AndroidSDK doesn't have fastboot. I checked all directories. It seems that they removed it in the latest release on Ubuntu (tools rev19, platform-tools rev11). Where can I get fastboot without building it? I'm still stuck in KF loading screen.

Comment: Everything's OK now. I updated SDK using SDK Manager and fastboot appeared! O.o

Comment: @Emerald214 If I'm not mistaken the Linux version of the SDK didn't come with fastboot until recently, so that's why the update helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the fastboot command not working on Mac. Turns out the binary files needed to be included in the $PATH variable. Here's the info I found that helped me resolve this.

On Mac OS, you'll need to add the "Platform Tools" directory to your $PATH variable. That means opening up a terminal, typing "sudo nano /etc/paths," entering your password, and adding the path of the "Platform Tools" directory to the bottom of the file. Then hit "control+X" on the keyboard, "y" and then "enter" to save, and you're done. Then you just need to run "flash-all.sh" from the terminal.

Rather than adding the path, I just copied the adb and fastboot files to the usr/bin folder since that path was already in there.

Source: http://androidforums.com/threads/problems-trying-to-flash-factory-image.948151/